# What does the notation "$.something = {" mean?

Tags: jquery

If there is this code inside a js file :

```
(function($) {
  $.cleditor = {
  ...
  };
  ...
})(jQuery);
```

It's the first time I see the notation `$.` : so what does it mean ?

Comment: `$` is just a shortcut for the global `jQuery` object, and the dot notation is the standard way of accessing object methods and properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$. is used to call the jquery methods like $.trim(), `(function($) { })(jQuery)` is `Immediately-Invoked Function Expression` or **in simple words self invoking on anonymous function**. You can read more about this notation over **[here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/22/function%E2%80%A6-vs-function%E2%80%A6-or-domready-vs-the-module-pattern/)**.

Comment: Thank you for the website : now it's clear the differences between the two declarations !

Answer (score 1):

That just means a new custom `function` has been added to the jQuery core.

Although a quick search on cleditor reveals that it is a jQuery plugin, and is supposed to be used like so:

```
$(selector).cleditor({options}); // where selector is either an input or textarea element
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, jQuery uses "$" as a shortcut for "jQuery"

Therefore - using $(".class") or jQuery(".class") is the same.

When writing plugins to avoid problems you can pass 'jQuery' to a function:

```
function($) {

//use $ writing your plugin

}(jQuery)
```

Now, $.cleditor Object contains global properties and methods used to create custom plugins and override built in functionality.

Following link will give you more idea of $.cleditor

http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/docs/GettingStarted.html